# How do I call an event for another component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I've been working in react for about.. 2 days.  3/4's of that was me trying to get react to work with my current Asp.net MVC WebApp.

I have 2 classes. Everything is working fine, but I want the `handleScan` of `Camera` to call the `handleHideClick()` of `ShowScanner`.  Whats the proper way to do that?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import QrReader from 'react-qr-reader';
import { unmountComponentAtNode, render } from "react-dom";

class Camera extends React.Component {
    state = {
        result: 'No result'
    }

    handleScan = data => {
        if (data) {
            this.setState({
                result: data
            });
            scanDataProcessor(this.state.result);
            unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('root'));
            // *** Replace unmount above with a call to execute:  ShowScanner.handleHideClick()
        }
    }
    handleError = err => {
        console.error(err)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="scanner" class="">
                <QrReader
                    delay={300}
                    onError={this.handleError}
                    onScan={this.handleScan}
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class ShowScanner extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleShowClick = this.handleShowClick.bind(this);
        this.handleHideClick = this.handleHideClick.bind(this);
        this.state = { showCamera: false }
    }

    handleShowClick() {
        this.setState({ showCamera: true });
        render(<Camera />, document.getElementById('root'));
    }

    handleHideClick() {
        this.setState({ showCamera: false });
        unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('root'));
    }

    render() {
        const showCamera = this.state.showCamera;
        let button;
        if (showCamera) {
            return (
                <button id="btnScan" type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-1" onClick={this.handleHideClick}>
                    <i class="bi bi-qr-code-scan"></i>
                    <br />Scan
                </button>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <button id="btnScan" type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-1" onClick={this.handleShowClick}>
                    <i class="bi bi-qr-code-scan"></i>
                    <br />Scan
                </button>
            );
        }
    }

}
render(<ShowScanner />, document.getElementById('scanBtn'));
```

At the very least, I need to reset the button so that when they click it, it remounts the `Camera` component without them having to click it twice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pass a reference of the function `handleHideClick` to the `Camera` component like so: `<Camera func={this.handleHideClick} />`. And then call it from inside `Camera` like so `this.props.func()`. General suggestion: switch to hooks.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the React docs. `Camera` is essentially a child of `ShowScanner` and could receive `handleScan` as a prop. You'd need to get this code a bit more conventionally React for that to be possible. https://reactjs.org/

Comment: @codemonkey thanks! Forgive me, but where do I add the reference?  I tried before and after the ```render``` in ```handleShowClick()``` and put the ```this.props.func()``` at the end of the ```handleScan``` but that didn't seem to do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: @codemonkey Ah!  Figured it out!  Thanks man!  Not before or after, but in it lol: ```render(<Camera func={this.handleHideClick} />, document.getElementById('root'));```